# CoffeeScript is converted into wrong javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following CoffeeScript

```
Excelsior.TopicView = Ember.View.extend
templateName: 'topic',
    didInsertElement :() ->
      this._super()
      Ember.run.scheduleOnce 'afterRender', this, ->
        converter = new Markdown.Converter()
    editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter)
    editor.run()
```

And the javascript it generates is

```
(function() {
  Excelsior.TopicView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'topic',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var editor;
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      var converter;
      return converter = new Markdown.Converter();
    });
    editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
    editor.run();
   }
 });

}).call(this);
```

This is not correct and what I actually want to generate is

```
(function() {
  Excelsior.TopicView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'topic',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      var converter= new Markdown.Converter();
      var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
      editor.run();
    });
   }
 });
}).call(this);
```

How can I fix my coffeescript?

Comment: Your Coffee indentation is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with indent (make sure you're not mixing spaces and tabs):

```
Excelsior.TopicView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'topic',
  didInsertElement :() ->
    this._super()
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce 'afterRender', this, ->
      converter = new Markdown.Converter()
      editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter)
      editor.run()
```